Package original jar with fallback native executable
I am trying to create a native image for my spring boot application using the native-image -jar <jarname> command.
Due to the use of reflection it is creating a fallback executable, which I am fine with. However, I want to bundle the original jar in the native executable itself so that I can distribute the binary as a single file. Any way to do this?
Due to some operational reasons the business requirement is to give an executable instead of a jar.

For creating spring boot native binary you can use mvn -ntp package -Pnative native:compile command, not native-image
